# Additional buttons in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to create additional buttons in fancybox (close around border of image).
I tried to use `beforeShow()` and `afterShow()` method, but when I call inside `this.content` or `this.inner`, I get a  javascript error - those variables are undefined.

Other thing is, that I have to get other attributes of each A element. So when I call `this.rel`, or `this.alt` I've got undefined error again.

Do you have some ideas how to find a solution for my problem?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you are trying or build a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending any new *html* to the `.fancybox-wrap` container using the `afterShow` callback like:

```
afterShow : function(){
 var myContent = '<div id="myContent">{my html content here}</div>'; 
 $(".fancybox-wrap").append(myContent);
}
```

use `CSS` to position (absolutely) the new content inside the box

it would be also a good idea to remove it `afterClose`, otherwise it would be added over again next time you open fancybox

```
afterClose: function(){
 $(".fancybox-wrap #myContent").remove();
}
```

On the other hand, in order to get other attributes from the selector that fired fancybox, use `$(this.element)` inside any callback function like:

```
beforeShow: function(){
 var thisAlt = $(this.element).attr("alt");
 var thisRel = $(this.element).attr("rel");
}
```

you can also use HTML5 `data-*` attributes like

```
<a class="fancybox" data-width="500" data-height="320" ....
```

and get their values like

```
var thisWidth = $(this.element).data("width");
var thisHeight = $(this.element).data("height");
```

or assign directly a new size to fancybox using those values like

```
afterShow: function(){
   this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
   this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
}
```

**NOTE**: all this information applies to fancybox v2.x. only.